# Automate The Boring Stuff Chapter 3: Zig-Zag exercise

Tags: python, output

I am having a hard time figuring out why my code does not work as it is supposed to.
Instead of a proper zig-zag, my output looks like a bunch of asterisks not doing anything.

```py
import time, sys

indent = 0 # How many spaces to indent.
indentIncreasing = True #Whether or not the indent increases

try:
    while True:
        #The main program loop
        print(' ' * indent, end='')
        print('********')
        time.sleep(0.1) # Pause for 1/10 of a second.
    
    if indentIncreasing:
        
        #Increase the number of spaces:
        indent = indent + 1
        if indent == 20:
            indentIncreasing = False
       # Change direction:
        else:
            #decrease the number of spaces:
            indent = indent - 1
            if indent == 0:
                #Change direction:
                indentIncreasing = True
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

My output:
[image]

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Could you include the desired behaviour and current output that you are getting?

Comment: Yea I posted it in some links, hope it is good enough since this is my first post ever. :D

Comment: Speaking of indentation, I think you need to indent the code block starting with `if indentIncreasing:` and up to `else`.

Comment: Right now, the `if` statement is outside of the while loop, so `indent` never changes.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop you have used is an infinite loop (since it does not have an updation or jump statement).
A proper `while` loop should have the following four:

1. Initialisation of the control variable,
2. Test statement of `while` loop,
3. Body of the loop, and
4. Updation of the control variable.

Edit your code in such a way that the while loop isn't an infinite loop.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When executing this code I got the same result. Zigzag didn't want to wave, so I changed this code a bit and now it is waving.

```py
import time, sys

indent = 0 # How many spaces to indent.

def print_symbol(symbol):
    print(' ' * indent, end='')
    print(symbol)
    time.sleep(0.1) # Pause for 1/10 of a second

try:
    #The main program loop
    while True:
        print_symbol('********')
        #Increase the number of spaces:
        indent = indent + 1
        if indent == 20:
            #Reduction the number of spaces:
            for i in range(0, indent):
                indent = indent - 1
                print_symbol('********')
      
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).